# Display users who voted on post acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the acts_as_votable gem and have implemented it so that a user can vote on a post model. What I want to do is when I display the posts I want to list what users voted for it. I currently display the score by:

```
<%= post.cached_votes_score %>
```

In the posts/index.html.erb This works great. I just cant get my head around how to display the users who voted. Ideally I want to show user.image.

Here is the code so far:

model/concern/votes.rb

```
def up_vote
  @post = find_post
  @post.liked_by current_user
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for voting #{current_user.name}"
  redirect_to @post
end
```

Iv added it so that user is the voter and the post is votable.

I also added cached migration:

```
class AddCachedVotesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
 add_column :posts, :cached_votes_total, :integer, :default => 0
 add_column :posts, :cached_votes_score, :integer, :default => 0
 add_column :posts, :cached_votes_up, :integer, :default => 0
 add_column :posts, :cached_votes_down, :integer, :default => 0
 add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score, :integer, :default => 0
 add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total, :integer, :default => 0
 add_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average, :float, :default => 0.0
 add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_total
 add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_score
 add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_up
 add_index  :posts, :cached_votes_down
 add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_score
 add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_total
 add_index  :posts, :cached_weighted_average
end

def self.down
 remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_total
 remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_score
 remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_up
 remove_column :posts, :cached_votes_down
 remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_score
 remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_total
 remove_column :posts, :cached_weighted_average
end
end
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Also do let me know if you want me to add any code above.

EDIT Here is link to the gem https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Comment: Does `post.voters` work?

Comment: @JoeKennedy im afraid not. I get undefined method voters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get list of all voters id for the post using below code

```
 @post.votes_for_ids
```

Comment: Hey @Icicle that has got me the ID's thats great step. on my user model I have an image field. Do you know how I might be able to print that with those IDs?

Comment: Try using below snippet which will give user User object which can be used to get image field data

@post.votes_for.voters

Comment: perfect got it :) much appreciated.

Comment: For those interested here is the code 
<% @post.votes_for.voters.each do |p| %>
      <%= image_tag(p.image) %>
<% end %>

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below code to get user name

```
@post.vote_by
```

Comment: it returns false. As in prints false in the view.