# Listing users that voted on post using acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display the images of the users who've upvoted a post using the  [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem, exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406736/display-users-who-voted-on-post-acts-as-votable). The problem is the answer that worked for that question is not working in my case.

I display the upvotes count like this:

```
<%= @post.cached_votes_total %>
```

I've added 'acts_as_votable' and 'acts_as_voter' into the post and user models.

The controller:

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  @post.liked_by current_user
end
```

The accepted answer in the above question is this:

```
<% @post.votes_for.voters.each do |p| %> 
  <%= image_tag(p.image) %> 
<% end %>
```

However this gives me an 'undefined method `votes_for' ' error.

```
<% @post.votes.each do |user| %>
  <%= user %>
<% end %>
```

This gives no error but I can't access the user's image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it by playing around a bit more.

```
<% @post.votes.by_type(User).voters.each do |user| %>
```